# Maven install node modules in target directory

Tags: node.js, maven, npm

In my pom.xml this is how my front-end-maven-plugin config looks like.
My package.json and gulpfiles are in the projects root directory.

```
<plugin>        
<groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice 
                            in your build log. -->
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>

                        <configuration>
                            <!-- optional: The default argument is actually "install", so unless 
                                you need to run some other npm command, you can remove this whole <configuration> 
                                section. -->
                            <arguments>install ./target/node_modules</arguments>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>gulp</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>gulp</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>replace-runner-start</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>javascript tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>karma</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <!-- optional: the default plase is "test". Some developers choose 
                            to run karma in the "integration-test" phase. -->
                        <phase>test</phase>

                        <configuration>
                            <!-- optional: the default is "karma.conf.js" in your working directory -->
                            <karmaConfPath>src/main/karma_webapp_all_conf.js</karmaConfPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <workingDirectory>src/main</workingDirectory> -->
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                    <nodeVersion>v6.11.3</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

when i run mvn clean install like this i get node installed in target but node_modules cannot be installed there because the folder does not exist. Is there a way without another plugin to make the directory and install the node_modules there.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still has this issue I suggest these options:

- Set the `install directory` to `target` in the "Frontend Maven Plugin": https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#installation-directory
- Don't use `target` at all for local development, but use the "Spring Boot DevTools" which handles everything in `src` and is my preferred way: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools
- If you REALLY need `node_modules` in `target`, use the "Maven Resources Plugin" to copy the folder into target: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like node_modules path is given wrong. Check the path of your node_modules. This can be done by

**Global libraries**

You can run `npm list -g` to see where global libraries are installed.

On Unix systems they are normally placed in `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` when installed globally. If you set the NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

Windows XP - `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules`
Windows 7, 8 and 10 - `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

**Non-global libraries**

Non-global libraries are installed the node_modules sub folder in the folder you are currently in.

You can `run npm list` to see the installed non-global libraries for your current location.